# Share point list and Display Name in PowerAutomate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a flow that works with a list of share point . When you change one column in another, the name of the one who changed using "Display Name" appears. The problem is that after the name of the person who changed the column appears, after a couple of seconds it changes to mine (the creator of the list) .Since my Flow updates the list item, the last updated by will change to me and the Flow runs again and i have infonity loop, i dont know how to set up a filter or smt else. I will be glad for any opinions.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to understand your problem, let me know if I took it wrongly. This is a common issue with the trigger you're using, and **it is by design**. I hope I'm right, you're probably using "When an item is created or modified".

The idea is to utilize the **Trigger Conditions** when you look for **Settings** of the trigger.
Example if you're using UserA when building the flow, you could use condition such as:

- if the "modified by" column is not equal UserA. But then you have to test the flow using another user.
- Add a custom column "Yes/No" with the name "Execute Automation", and instruct user to select "Yes". Then add condition if the "Execution Automation" column is true.

There are many ways to prevent that infinite loop.

Reference: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Power-Automate-Trigger-Conditions-made-EASY/ba-p/441348

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have already solved this problem but your way of avoiding flow loops is just as valid. I hope it will be useful to someone else